# CMake two source files with the same name

Tags: c++, cmake

Question is pretty simple, If i have CMake project with the following structure

sources/foo.cpp

sources/bar/foo.cpp

Does cmake guaranties lack of compile conflicts with same file names in different directories?

Comment: "Does cmake guaranties lack of compile conflicts with same file names in different directories?" - Yes, CMake guarantees that. That is, would you face with some problem in that area, then you could fill bugreport for CMake and they will fix the problem in 99% cases (the rest 1% cases are for "impossible to fix"). Note, that some CMake generators produce funny names for object files created from sources with "duplicate" names. But whatever names of the object files, their linkage should be performed flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does cmake guaranties lack of compile conflicts with same file names in different directories?

Cmake will work with no problem with two files with same name. It would be pretty useless if it wouldn't.

As for "guaranties", from [cmake licensing](https://cmake.org/licensing/):

> CMake is distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-clause License.

On the end of [BSD 3 clause license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_(%22BSD_License_2.0%22,_%22Revised_BSD_License%22,_%22New_BSD_License%22,_or_%22Modified_BSD_License%22)) and in [cmake sources/copyright.txt](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Copyright.txt) you may read:

> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. [...]

The software is free and there is no guarantee of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes cmake handles it

I created 3 files:

```
codeTest.h
codeTest.cpp
src/codeTest.cpp
```

defined a function that prints data in `codeTest.cpp` in root directory and and defined "main" function in `src/codeTest.cpp` and used the print function in "main" then compiled it using cmake

```
add_executable(codeTest src/codeTest.cpp codeTest.cpp)
```

and it worked

**codeTest.h**

```
#ifndef CODETEST_H_
#define CODETEST_H_


#include<stdio.h>

void printTest();

#endif /* CODETEST_H_ */
```

**codeTest.cpp**

```
#include <../codeTest.h>

void printTest()
{
    printf(" void printTest() \n");
}
```

**src/codeTest.cpp**

```
#include <../codeTest.h>

int main()
{
    printTest();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The solution is to change cmake version form 3.6 to 3.24.

Comment: Cmake version is too old

Comment: Please [edit] to include the explanation into the answer itself and to avoid the "Me too" misinterpretation. E.g. "Your problem is too old a cmake version, the solution is to ...".